# "Wanting to do" without being "able to do"?

Tags: motivation, self-control, procrastination

For those with disordered avoidance, a common theme is the inability to do something which is beneficial and, perhaps more importantly, even pleasurable.

For those that study motivation, intrinsic or otherwise...

In the situation where one chooses to do nothing or something else --not because it is preferable or more enjoyable but simply because they are unable to psychologically tolerate the object of their own desire....

**Question**: *what does it mean to "want to" if one is unable to force oneself to do*? And, what areas of the brain are competing in such a struggle with the self?

(Differentiate this from procrastination in which there is a preference for one active over another in the short term)

Comment: Do you mean [Avoidant Personality Disorder](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/avoidant-personality-disorders#1)?

Comment: @AliceD Nope, not a diagnostic but a differentiation between self-desire and self-efficacy from the perspective of personal agency. But more importantly, I'm curious about the brain regions responsible for the intrinsic motivation in a genuine "want to" and the "no-go" inability of "unable to force".